# Aligning images responsively

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 3 images horizontally & responsively so the images become vertical when a user visits the website on a mobile device.

I am having a few problems since the alignment does not work properly & for some reason my "border-radius" property is not applying.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxL7d0e1/

CSS:

```
#portfolio{
background-color: : white;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#portfolio h1{
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 400px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
}

#portfolio h2{
 font-size: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
}

.project img{
 padding: 50px;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Comment: `.project img` shoud be changed to `.project figure img` that should fix your border radius problem. As for the alignment problem i cant see any since the images are vertically stacking as expected

Comment: what is your specific problem? can you be detailed about what is going wrong?

Comment: @ImmortalDude when I remove the padding it works, otherwise it down not. this is the current alignment and it seems fine up until I reduce the size of the window. I want the horizontal alignment to become vertical once on media https://gyazo.com/096794da3aa807f9d73f08b0efa5fdd6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here it is. The stacking is a simple issue to solve. In this case I've used `inline-block` display to have the containers in a row, and a `media` query to change their width to 100% on screen sizes less than 700px.

```
.project {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  margin-right:-4px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .project {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

For the `border-radius` problem, you were using example images with whitespace inside them, which was throwing off the visuals. Check this updated fiddle with everything working properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/hxL7d0e1/2/

Comment: I would like the images to be horizontally stacked like this: https://gyazo.com/acf794cb216b4b91de6892f1d81c49ac

Comment: @moe On small screens as well? If so just remove the media query

Comment: nevermind I did a silly mistake, it works! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Using the firefox debugger i was able to see that your image has alot of white space around it. The blue rectangle is inside another bigger white rectangle. Could you use an image without that white space. See link to your image below;

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Rectangle_.png

You could change the background of your whole page to something like red and you'll see what am talking about.